# False with regular expression from properties file

Tags: java, regex, properties

so here is my problem. I have string like comment in Java:

```
String s = "// the "then" clause: decrease"
```

And when I'm doing this:

```
System.out.println(s.matches("(^(//).+)"));
```

Its `true`.
But, when i have properties file, where

```
listing = "(^(//).+)"
```

And doing the same

```
System.out.println(s.matches(resourceBundle.getString("listing")));
```

I'm receiving `false`. Why? And what regex must be in properties to receive true? Thanks

Comment: If you print out `resourceBundle.getString("listing")`, what does it say?

Comment: here is sout: `"(^(//).+)"` the same regex

Comment: It is probably because you have to escape the //, can you put this in the properties file `listing = "(^(\/\/).+)"` and see what this does?

Comment: Just to make sure: are quotes also part of sout (because they probably shouldn't be there)?

Comment: @TimvanderLippe In Java regex engine `/` is not special character so it doesn't require escaping.

Comment: Also are you sure that when you execute `s.matches(resourceBundle.getString("listing"))` `s` contains text starting with `//`?

Comment: I think the comment of @Pshemo is correct. In a properties file you shouldnt add quotes for strings. So `listing = (^(//).+)` should fix it?

Comment: yes, thanks, without quotes it works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove quotation mark in your properties file.

```
listing = (^(//).+)
```